# Referencing handler from another class

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, android-handler, rx-android

I have a service that's running some processes in the background using a handler.

In another class using rxjava, I'm referencing that particular handler the observable is doing work on.

```
.subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(ReadWriteTransportService.mMessageHandler))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Am I going to get in trouble with memory issues...by referencing the service's instance field like that?

What is a better way to reference that handler from out of the class?

Answer (score 1):

HandlerScheduler will keep the reference to ReadWriteTransportService until your Observabe do not complete or Subscriver unsubcribe.

to avoid memory leaks unsubscribe from observabe when you don't need it anymore